# Tag badge descriptions on help center page are inconsistent

Tags: feature-request, badges, help-center

The `help/badges` page seems to have an inconsistency with the tone of certain badge descriptions. Normal badges have descriptions like:

- Question score of 10 or more
- Answered first question with score of 1 or more
- First up vote

But the tag badges are:

- You must have a total score of X in at least Y non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

"you must" and "this badge" are boilerplate that the other descriptions don't have. Why? Shouldn't it be more like this?:

- Have a total score of X in at least Y non-community wiki answers for this tag